# shared preference issue not update

Tags: android, cordova

I have been develop android app. I have two app A, B. In A, i create a file shared preference with:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("account", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

And in B, i get data from sharedPref of B. But i have problem:
When i update file sharedPref in A with new value and open app B from A to read data in  sharedPref. Value retreived is not correct, it is old value, it not update for App B. I remove and restart app B then it get value correct( new value). Can you help me. Thanh you so much.

```
editor.putString("username", user);
editor.putString("password", pass);
editor.commit();
MainActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
MainActivity.this.finish();
MainActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.inet.solution");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("account", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

**For**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("account", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank. But i want read file from many app, if MODE_PRIVATE then i only use for one App.

Comment: Then change MODE_PRIVATE for MODE_APPEND

Answer (score 0):

> You use this one

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("account", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

[Try this links which is helpful](http://chrisrisner.com/Accessing-the-Shared-Preferences-of-a-Different-Application-in-Android)